# How can I get the second user Id in a two user id's in the same field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have a only two user chat that puts both user id's in a field (to make it a new id). I need to get the second Id and show letter in a list. How can I get the second part of the id after the hyphen

```
{
  "chat" : {
    "st98ySAm5CNeq2WVDTCAQJ3ZcpP2-2C95b9MJprgpCITMXknPuXS52mR2" : {
      "-M9Qk0mmv-r2C0kaFqpn" : {
        "_id" : 1591750954541,
        "createdAt" : 1591750954541,
        "order" : -1591750954541,
        "text" : "Hello there",
        "uid" : "2C95b9MJprgpCITMXknPuXS52mR2"
      },
      "-M9QkBv-rl18Nc4OyfpV" : {
        "_id" : 1591751000122,
        "createdAt" : 1591751000122,
        "order" : -1591751000122,
        "text" : "Hello",
        "uid" : "st98ySAm5CNeq2WVDTCAQJ3ZcpP2"
      }
    },
    "st98ySAm5CNeq2WVDTCAQJ3ZcpP2-heGJLHnvwMgofczT9PHSlRwANCB2" : {
      "-M9_eYajRuO0RjGDJHSM" : {
        "_id" : 1591917295564,
        "createdAt" : 1591917295564,
        "order" : -1591917295564,
        "text" : "Mmmm",
        "uid" : "heGJLHnvwMgofczT9PHSlRwANCB2"
      },
      "-M9_efDQ1qHUrLMndU2o" : {
        "_id" : 1591917327330,
        "createdAt" : 1591917327330,
        "order" : -1591917327330,
        "text" : "How are you BIG MAN",
        "uid" : "st98ySAm5CNeq2WVDTCAQJ3ZcpP2"
      }
    },
    "yKaXQZCbn8RdxO96tsbf9ZQHK3g1-2C95b9MJprgpCITMXknPuXS52mR2" : {
      "-M9QUli8eRb7gEEwgIM8" : {
        "_id" : 1591746694381,
        "createdAt" : 1591746694381,
        "order" : -1591746694381,
        "text" : "Hello",
        "uid" : "2C95b9MJprgpCITMXknPuXS52mR2"
      },
      "-M9Qji3QtqOKYrRZV7Wg" : {
        "_id" : 1591750873750,
        "createdAt" : 1591750873750,
        "order" : -1591750873750,
        "text" : "Hi bro",
        "uid" : "yKaXQZCbn8RdxO96tsbf9ZQHK3g1"
      },
      "-M9QjwXH4diBq0mj_aPz" : {
        "_id" : 1591750933005,
        "createdAt" : 1591750933005,
        "order" : -1591750933005,
        "text" : "Hi how are you",
        "uid" : "2C95b9MJprgpCITMXknPuXS52mR2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I split the id into to and took the second part but this way it makes multiple arrays each time it loops and and creates some empty objects

```
componentDidMount() {
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref()
      .child("chat")
      .on("child_added", snapshot => {
          const anotherUsers = [];
          let array = snapshot.key.split("-");
          let a = array[1];
          anotherUsers.push({
            key: a
          });
          this.setState({
            unknownUser2: anotherUsers
          });
     
      });
}
```

Comment: Did you try anything yet? It is much more likely that folks here will help you if you show what you've already done. Without that, it is unlikely we'll explain things better than the documentation already does.

Comment: after you get the complete id field, it looks like you can apply string methods related to that field. Haven't you tried anything ?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I did some changes to explane more

Comment: @CanUver check now I explained little bite more

Comment: Two more questions: 1) You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do. 2) Given that JSON as input, what do you expect the state to become?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i didn't understood "give Json input " I expect the state should be the second part of the id that is the other person that is chating with the current user. and once I get the that state(user id ) then i will show in list.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
componentDidMount() {
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref()
      .child("chat")
      .on("child_added", snapshot => {
          const unknown = [...this.state.unknownUser2];
          let array = snapshot.key.split("-");
          let a = array[1];
          const updated=[...unKnown,{key: a}]
          this.setState({
            unknownUser2: updated
          });
     
      });
}
```

Comment: now it became one array but there is an empty array that prints the first time and when I try to use the key then there are two empty keys even though I filtered the array. I need to use that key to retrive data from firestore to get user avatar .etc so it throws error that says "Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: undefined"
 when I say .doc(this.state.unknownUser2.key)

Answer (score 0):

To show the second part of each key under `chat`, it is probably easier to use a `value` event:

```
firebase
  .database()
  .ref()
  .child("chat")
  .on("value", snapshot => {
      const anotherUsers = [];
      snapshot.forEach((child) => {
         const second = child.key.split("-")[1];
         anotherUsers.push({ key: second });
      });
      this.setState({
        unknownUser2: anotherUsers
      });
  });
```

Comment: now it became one array but there is an empty array that prints the first time and when I try to use the key then there are two empty keys even though I filtered the array. I need to use that key to retrive data from firestore to get user avatar .etc so it throws error that says "Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: undefined"
 when I say .doc(this.state.unknownUser2.key)